# Error en el query PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

tengo un error en esta consulta puse un "echo" para revisar que si le llegaran los datos y aparecieron todos trate de quitar el mas reciente que era "id_users" pero me sige terando el mismo error.

```
<?php

include ("../bd.php");

if (isset($_POST['guardar_tarea'])) {
    $titulo = $_POST['titulo'];
    $descripcion = $_POST['descripcion'];
    $estado = $_POST['estado'];
    $fecha = $_POST['fecha'];
    $id_usu = $_SESSION['id_usu'];
    $query = "INSERT INTO task(title, description, estado, date, id_users) VALUES ('$titulo', '$descripcion', '$estado', '$fecha', '$id_usu')";
    $result = mysqli_query($conectarbd, $query);
    if (!$result) {
        die("Fallo en query");
    }

    $_SESSION['mensaje'] = "Tarea Guardada Con Exito";
    $_SESSION['tipo-mensaje'] = 'success';
    mysqli_close($conectarbd);

    header("Location: ../index.php");
}

?>
```

El error que me sale es

> Error en el query

Ya que haci mismo lo programe

si pongo

```
die("Fallo en query ".mysqli_error($conectarbd));
```

me sale este error

> Fallo en query Duplicate entry '7' for key 'id_users'

Gracias

Comment: El error es Error en el query ya que haci mismo lo puse en la segunda condicional if
Ya lo edite muchas gracias

Comment: En lugar de un mensaje genérico, podés reportar un mensaje específico. Referite a https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.error.php para mayor detalle.

Comment: Coloca temporalmente el mensaje de error para saber cuál es la causa exacta: `die("Fallo en query ".mysqli_error($conectarbd));`

Comment: Me sale este error al poner die("Fallo en query ".mysqli_error($conectarbd)); 
Fallo en query Duplicate entry '7' for key 'id_users'
el 'id_users' es una columna de la base de datos

Comment: Me suena que hay columnas especificadas como UNIQUE o como índice en la tabla `task`, y estás tratando de guardar valores que ya existen en esas columnas. Podrías poner el resultado de un `DESCRIBE task;` para analizar la estructura.

Comment: El mensaje de error es claro hora. Te está diciendo que la columna `id_users` tiene una restricción de llave primaria o unique, por tanto la tabla no puede tener más de una fila con el mismo valor. En este caso, el valor `7` ya existe y no puedes insertar otra fila con `id_users=7`. Entonces, si esa columna debe continuar con esa restricción, lo mejor será revisar si el valor no existe antes de insertarlo. O, si la restricción no es correcta, deberás ejecutar un `ALTER TABLE` que quite esa restricción (deberás estar MUY SEGURO de lo que haces en ese caso).

Comment: Ya me funciono muchas gracias, nose si quieras ponerla como respuesta para darte el verificado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes configurada la columna **id_user** como unique en la tabla task, si la idea es que un usuario solo puede tener una tarea, debes validar antes de hacer el insert y notificar que el usuario ya tiene una tarea, o si un usuario puede tener varias tareas debes remover el unique de ese campo en la configuración de la tabla